# extracting .rar files with unrar-free and unar (need progress completion) and time stamp

Tags: debian, shell, rar, progress-information

I have been playing around with .rar files for sometime now.

I see unrar-free and unar and both seem to have the features I need. I need something which extracts .rar archives on the CLI with complete paths, having progress completion but respecting the file creation/modification time when the .rar archive was created.

The parts of both unrar and unar that  I like -

From unrar-free -

```
x         Extract files from archive with full path.
```

unrar - 1:0.0.1+cvs20140707-4

From unar -

```
-t, -copy-time
              Copy the file modification time from the archive file to the containing directory, if one is created.
```

unar - 1.10.1-2+b2

I do also like the fact that unar can extract till rarv5 instead of just being limited to 3.

The only thing which seems to be missing in progress bar completion along with the verbose output that unrar gives by default .

I do know that pv does progress completion but need something which doesn't need pv .

```
$ aptitude show pv
Package: pv                              
Version: 1.6.6-1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Maintainer: Antoine Beaupré <anarcat@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 123 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
Suggests: doc-base
Description: Shell pipeline element to meter data passing through pv (Pipe Viewer) can be inserted into any normal pipeline between two processes to give a visual indication of how quickly data is passing through, how long it has taken, how near to completion it is, and an estimate of how long it will be until completion. 

 To use it, insert it in a pipeline between two rocesses, with the appropriate options. Its standard input will be passed through to its standard output and progress will be shown on standard error.
Homepage: https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml
```

I am looking for something on the CLI rather than a GUI.

Having progress completion with lsar will also be a bonus.

I did a search of the questions here which are around similar topics as well as on the web but wasn't able to find something useful :(